# pass utf8 string from javascript's formData object to php by POST

Tags: javascript, php, post

I'm trying to pass a utf8 string from javascript to php through formData and POST.

My `javascript` code:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("downloadzip", zipFilename);

// send the request to php
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
let url = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname;
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
            $("#downloading-and-zipping").fadeOut(2000);
        } else {
            $("#error-downloading").show();
        }
    }
};
request.open("POST", url, true);
request.send(formData);
```

The `php` code that reads the POST data:

```
if (! empty($_POST) && ! empty($_POST["downloadzip"])) {
    error_log("ORIGINAL " . $_POST["downloadzip"]);
}
```

Now, the problem is: if `javascript`'s `zipFilename == "Misión"`, in `php` `$_POST["downloadzip"] == "Misi\xc3\xb3n"`.

Why is the string transformed?

How do I get the original string?

Comment: Does PHP know who to decode URI components?

Comment: That output [looks ok to me](https://3v4l.org/TqYrA#v8.3.0), unless you mean you get literal escape sequences in your log file. If that's the case, try `bin2hex()` to figure out the exact bytes.